# Hazelcast Webfilter session clustering not working with in 3.2 with Spring

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I created an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/2152):

I was wondering if anyone else is using a similar setup (Spring 3.2.2 + Hazelcast Webfilter for session clustering) successfully with Hazelcast 3.2 or be able to confirm that it isn't working for them either? Or if someone using Spring with an older version would like to take the time to try upgrading to 3.2 to see if it works for them.

- Matti Frimodig

Answer (score 0):

Do you followed the advices mentioned there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/ASplQrp4DDA

??